# system.net.sockets.socketexception the remote server closed connection

Tags: c#

I have this code on my server side.

```
public static void Data_IN(object cSocket)
{      
    Socket clientSocket = (Socket)cSocket;

    byte[] Buffer;
    int readBytes;

    while (true)
    {                
        Buffer = new byte[clientSocket.SendBufferSize];           
        readBytes = clientSocket.Receive(Buffer);

        if (readBytes > 0)
        {
            Packet p = new Packet(Buffer);
            DataManager(p);
        }
    }
}
```

And the main problem is that when I stop debugging the code the server always crashes and says

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: the remote server closed connection

The error is always at `readBytes = clientSocket.Recieve(Buffer)`;

That is the only way I can crash the server, my only concern is when someone uses the chat program that I have created and his/hers computer crashes the chat server will go down and I always need to restart the server.

Clientside code below which executes when closing the window

```
private void MainWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isConnected)
    {
        Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.CloseConnection, ID);

        p.data.Add(login);          
        p.data.Add("exits from chat");

        socket.Send(p.ToBytes());

        socket.Close();
        isConnected = false;
        thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

On below there is the code part which uses data_in, that code is on the client side

```
  private void ConnectBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Login.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Add username");
        }
        else if (!IPAddress.TryParse(serverIP.Text, out ipAdress))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Add valid ip");
        }
        else
        {
            ClearRequireMsg();

            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAdress, 4242);

            try
            {
                socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
                login = Login.Text;

                isConnected = true;
                ConnectBtn.IsEnabled = false;
                SendBtn.IsEnabled = true;

                thread = new Thread(Data_IN);
                thread.Start();
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                AddMsgToBoard("Error during connecting to server", "System");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: show the client code. Probably the stream might have disposed at the client end before server started to read

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa i'll ad the code now which happens when i close the window

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function Data_IN without passing any parameter.

```
thread = new Thread(Data_IN);
```

Right way:

```
new Thread(() => Data_IN(socket));
```

Comment: I tried that and now it's giving me a new error;
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'cannot access a disposed object.
objects name: System.Net.Sockets.Socket.'

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll and the spesific one is the 'Cannot acces a disposed object' @LoneDev

Comment: After the connection is closed, probably, the clientSocket object gets disposed automatically.
Update your answer adding the piece of code where you call Data_IN function so we can help you

Comment: just a sec, i'm adding it to the top